# Problems with outputting two dimensional arrays...?

Tags: java, arrays, list, dimensional

This is the beginnings of a program that organizes students and their grades from four different classes. Eventually I'll be adding averages and what-not. At the moment however I have a problem with outputting the grades in the 'studentListField' -- see below...after the 'addButton'.
    I'm pretty new to java and this particular program (netbeans) I'm using to build this, hence why I'm asking for guidance and help.**

```
package studentgrades;

import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */
public class StudentGradesView extends FrameView {

    **//This the all important array...you can list up to 5 students and list 4 test marks of each student.**
    int[][]aryStudent = new int [5][4];

    public StudentGradesView(SingleFrameApplication app) {

****// between here is just a bunch of stuff that was automatically added from when I built the GUI** 

}
    private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        **// left "[]" is the student... right "[]" holds the grades...
        // test1Field (1-4) is a JTextField where you input the test grade...I hope that was clear with the name I gave it...**
        aryStudent[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[0][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        aryStudent[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[1][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        aryStudent[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[2][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        aryStudent[3][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[3][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[3][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[3][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        aryStudent[4][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[4][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[4][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[4][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());

        aryStudent[5][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
        aryStudent[5][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
        aryStudent[5][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
        aryStudent[5][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());


        int student = 5;
        int marks = 4;

        for (int x=0; x < student ; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y < marks ; y++) {
                **//And if it did work it should output this along with the test scores...At least I hoped it would...**
                studentListField.setText(aryStudent[x][y] + "");
            }
            //System.out.println("");

            /**
             * This was the errors that came up...
             * 
             Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
             at studentgrades.StudentGradesView.addButtonActionPerformed(StudentGradesView.java:405)
             at studentgrades.StudentGradesView.access$800(StudentGradesView.java:22)
             at studentgrades.StudentGradesView$4.actionPerformed(StudentGradesView.java:182)
             at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
             at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
             at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
             at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
             at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
             at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
             */
        }
    }                                         

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton exitButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField firstNameField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel firstNameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField lastNameField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lastNameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton listButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField studentListField;
    private javax.swing.JTextField test1Field;
    private javax.swing.JTextField test2Field;
    private javax.swing.JTextField test3Field;
    private javax.swing.JTextField test4Field;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private final Timer messageTimer;
    private final Timer busyIconTimer;
    private final Icon idleIcon;
    private final Icon[] busyIcons = new Icon[15];
    private int busyIconIndex = 0;

    private JDialog aboutBox;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a ArrayList<Students> and access grades by a field? Each student has a grade..seems like the perfect place to  make a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the size of your array `int[][]aryStudent = new int [5][4];` to be 5 and you are going from 0 to 5 (which is 6)

```
aryStudent[5][0] = Integer.parseInt(test1Field.getText());
aryStudent[5][1] = Integer.parseInt(test2Field.getText());
aryStudent[5][2] = Integer.parseInt(test3Field.getText());
aryStudent[5][3] = Integer.parseInt(test4Field.getText());
```

As suggested in the comments, use an `ArrayList`. The advantage with an `ArrayList` is that they dynamically grow in size so you don't have to worry about the maximum size.

Or, the best way IMHO, would be to use a `HashMap`
Example:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> studentsMarks = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
//To insert
studentsMarks.put(//key, //value);
//To retrive
studentMarks.get(//key);
```

Comment: OP this seems to satisfy your question, no? Why not select this as the answer?